# In Laravel how can I validate an select option multiply type array (name[])?

Tags: laravel, validation

Validate a named select option input type name[] multiply in the validation options that have laravel version 5.6?

According to the documentation, I tried to validate it that way, but it doesn't work for me

One way

```
<select name="office[]">
```

---

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'office.*' => 'required'
        ], [
            'office.required' => __('My message')
        ]);
```

Otra que tampoco me funciona

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'office'   => "required|array|min:1",
            "office.*"  => "required|integer|min:1",
        ], [
            'office.*.required' => __('Debes agregar alguna sucursal')
        ]);
```

I could be helped by please !!!

PS:I'm with version 5.6.*

Answer (score 0):

For something as complex as an array I would use [Custom Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#custom-validation-rules). That would allow you to write a function and pass the validation however you want.

```php
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
   if(/** Array complies with your rules **/) {
       return true;
   }
}
```